# Not able to configure JPA with ehcache

Tags: java, jpa, ehcache

I have been trying to configure JPA with ehcache but no success till now. The configurations which i am doing are :

- persistence.xml

  ```
  <persistence-unit name="customDatabase">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/oracleXE_DS</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.td.waw.cse.entities.Product</class>
    <properties>
                     <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
             <property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="net.sf.ehcache.openjpa.datacache.EhCacheQueryCache"/>
     <property name="openjpa.DataCacheManager" value="net.sf.ehcache.openjpa.datacache.EhCacheDataCacheManager"/>
     <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="net.sf.ehcache.openjpa.datacache.EhCacheDataCache"/>
     <property name="openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider" value="net.sf.ehcache.openjpa.datacache.NoOpRemoteCommitProvider"/>
  </properties>
  ```
- ehcache.xml

  ```
  <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
           updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"
           dynamicConfig="true" >
      <defaultCache
      maxElementsInMemory="1000"
      eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"
      timeToLiveSeconds="600"
      overflowToDisk="false"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
      />

      <!-- OpenJPA data cache -->
      <cache name="openjpa"
      maxElementsInMemory="5000"
      eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"
      timeToLiveSeconds="600"
      overflowToDisk="false"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
      />

      <!-- OpenJPA query cache -->
      <cache name="openjpa-querycache"
      maxElementsInMemory="1000"
      eternal="false"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"
      timeToLiveSeconds="600"
      overflowToDisk="false"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
      />
  </ehcache>
  ```
- Product.java

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="PRODUCT")
  @NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="getAllProducts", query = "select products from Product products")})
  public class Product implements Serializable {}
  ```

I am not getting any exception but i could not see the ehcache working as nothing specific to ehcache printed in the logs.
I would really appreciate if someone can help in this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is _not_ a forum, please do not post an answer that does not solve the problem in your question. If you find yourself posting long code snippets, they should be a part of your _question_. I've removed several of your answers.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following properties in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="ehcache"/>
<property name="openjpa.DataCacheManager" value="ehcache"/>
```

Add the following jars in classpath:`ehcache-core-2.4.4.jar`, `ehcache-openjpa-0.2.0.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar`.

That's all.

**Jar Downloads:**

- link - http://ehcache.org/downloads/catalog?activated=true
- `ehcache-core-2.4.4.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` - *ehcache-core-2.4.4-distribution.tar.gz* module
- `ehcache-openjpa-0.2.0.jar` - *ehcache-openjpa-0.2.0-distribution.tar.gz*

**References**

- L2 caching explained - http://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_caching
- OpenJPA L2 caching implementation - http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/ref_guide_caching.html
- Ehcache OpenJPA implementation - http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/openjpa-provider

Answer (score 0):

DataNucleus works perfectly fine with EHCache, with the config specified here
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_2/jpa/cache.html#ehcache
It will print log messages about the L2 cache whenever it is accessed. You don't mention your JPA provider.